# Emacs's Theraphis (Eliza) API

Tags: emacs

Does anyone know if there is some way to send "questions" to the Emacs's therapist and retrieve the response back? (I'm writing some app, and would like to reuse its natural language processing capability)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unofficial API would be to look at the function bound to RET in "doctor-mode" and see what it does.  Then you might write some code and use emacsclient from your app to eval that code and passing data back and forth.

For example, I see that `doctor-read-print` sets the value of doctor-sent to the sentence written by the user, then increases doctor--lincount, and calls `doctor-doc` (you would need to parse the doctor's response from the buffer).

But since Eliza is a classic IA example, I am sure you may find free versions around, in several languages.

Comment: Could you tell me how to get emacs to eval expression without having to open emacs, type `M: <eval>`? In other words, can I pipe the expression to be evaluated to emacs or something like that?

Comment: You need an opened emacs (you can used --daemon if you don't want a window or terminal), then eval `(server-start)` on it.  Then you can use `emacsclient -e expression` to eval expressions.  Please note that doctor is stateful, so opening a new instance would not work.

Comment: Awesome! (I never actually knew about emacsclient) Thanks

Comment: How do I access the buffer from the client? So I started the server, leave the window open, and on another windows, I ran `emacslient -e "(doctor)"`, which starts the "therapist" windows on the first windows, which is good. But the response I got from the client is `nil` (while I was actually expecting to get the Welcome-message printed in the emacs windows)

Comment: The response you get is what the eval expression returns: `emacsclient -e '(+ 2 3))'` will print on stdout a 5, for example.  `(doctor)` does not return anything (it returns nil, in fact), it just write some stuff on a buffer.  You need to write some code to read stuff from that buffer and return it.